# advice on how to best to reveal additional content based on the contents height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a #banner that holds content, basically what i want to do is show a certain amount of the content and then have a more button that will show the rest of the content if clicked. This in turn will also animate the height of #banner, I have set the #banner height at 300px but want to find the height of the content #inner and animate this accordingly. At the moment I have the following version but reckon Im using a lot of #ids /  to achieve the effect, can anyone advise how I can make this better?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/43gTt/1/

Thanks
Kyle

Comment: Why add all those DIVs and IDs? You could do the same thing with just one DIV.

Comment: hi, all the divs at the moment because im not entirely sure of the best way to create this effect

Comment: But doesn't it work the same if you just remove them? I fail to see what they are used for at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you compute the height of the `inner` div and use that to animate.

```
var $tmpInner = inner.clone().appendTo('body');
var divHeight = $tmpInner.outerHeight();
$tmpInner.remove();
```

Below will compute the height of the innerDiv based on the content of the div.

Also, updated the css style for the banner to `overflow:hidden` so that you don't need separate animate for the banner.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/43gTt/24/)

**CSS:**

```
#banner{background:#dedede;overflow: hidden; }
#outer{margin:0 auto;width:200px;}
#middle{height:200px;overflow:hidden}
#inner{width:200px;margin:0 auto;}
.entry{display:none;}
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var outer = $('#outer'),
        middle = $('#middle'),
        inner = $('#inner'),
        /*innerH = inner.height(),*/
        banner = $('#banner'),
        more = $('#more');

    var $tmpInner = inner.clone().appendTo('body');
    var divHeight = $tmpInner.outerHeight();
    $tmpInner.remove();    

    // animate banner and #middle to reveal additional content
    more.on('click', function(e) {
        middle.animate({
            height: divHeight
        }, 300);

        /*banner.animate({
            height: innerH
        }, 300);*/
    });
});
```

**Note:** I am not sure why you need that many wrappers div, but I presume that would be part of your HTML. Also I will leave the code cleanup to you.